# How to access Property?

Tags: java, javers

From 1.4.0 release,
"PropertyChange is now decoupled from Property, reference from propertyChange to concrete property is replaced with propertyName String field."

What's the alternative way to access Property after 1.4.0 changes ? As I would like to access "looksLikeId" in Property

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with the following snippet:

```java
ManagedType managedType = (ManagedType)javers.getTypeMapping(Person.class);
Property property = managedType.getProperty(propertyChange.getPropertyName());
```

Full example (groovy):

```groovy
def "should extract Property from PropertyChange"(){
  given:
  def javers = JaversTestBuilder.newInstance()

  when:
  def diff = javers.compare(new Person('1','bob'), new Person('1','bobby'))
  PropertyChange propertyChange = diff.changes[0]

  ManagedType managedType = (ManagedType)javers.getTypeMapping(Person)
  Property property = managedType.getProperty(propertyChange.propertyName)

  then:
  property.name == 'name'
  !property.looksLikeId()
}
```

In version 1.4.1, I will add convenience `getProperty()` method to javers:

```
Property property = javers.getProperty( propertyChange )
```